# How to run MapReduce Program from local IDE on remote cluster

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have a simple MapReduce program which I want to run it on a remote cluster. I can do this from command line by simply running

```
hadoop jar myjar.jar input output
```

but when I want to run a function in my junit TestCase class from my IDE which invokes the MR job, I get the following warnings:

```
 WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter  - No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See Job or Job#setJar(String).
 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YARNRunner  - Job jar is not present. Not adding any jar to the list of resources.
```

although I have this line set, before submitting the MR job:

```
job.setJarByClass(MyJob.class);
```

and hence the job fails as it cannot find the appropriate classes (like MyMapKey which is the mapper key class) to operate.

```
Error: java.io.IOException: Initialization of all the collectors failed. Error in last collector was :java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class MyMapKey not found
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.createSortingCollector(MapTask.java:414)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.access$100(MapTask.java:81)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewOutputCollector.<init>(MapTask.java:698)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:770)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1709)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
```

any thoughts on this?

Comment: Are you sure that you have a jar file and not just compiled bunch of `*.class`es?

Comment: I am sure in the sense that, as an alternative way, when I use RunJar.main(...) in my test function and give the location of the same jar that I submit successfully through command line, I get the same errors.

Comment: I guess you are using MRUNIT for testing.
Can you provide any sample of the code that you have developed.
If you have developed using MRUNIT, you can simply run the test class as JUnit class. Reference :- https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MRUNIT/MRUnit+Tutorial

Comment: @DeepanRam No. I am using junit.framework.TestCase class and in one of my test functions, I call a function which in turn invokes my MR job. It looks like this:
    
    public void testMyJob() throws Exception {
        Driver.doMyJob();
    }

Comment: Can we try to specify the main class while running, something like:-
hadoop jar myjar.jar <fully qualified path of package and main class> input output

Comment: @DeepanRam I don't understand how that helps to my problem? I can already successfully run the program from command line!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should add remote Hadoop cluster config files (i.e. core-site.xml, hdfs-site.xml, mapred-site.xml, yarn-site.xml, ssl-client.xml) as resources to your Configuration object. Then follow the steps in the above link to see how you should add manually the job jar to classpath on remote cluster.